# Can not print in java console the min, avg, max value of a MySql table

Tags: java, mysql

How can I use resultset to get me the minimum, average or maximum value from a mysql database column?

I have a prepared statement sql constant string = Select avg(EntryValues) from Entries;

I know I need to use a resultset.getString(EntryValues) but I dont know how to build the java method that would return the actual average value from that resultset.next() loop thing...

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a `statement` from your `connection`
2. use the `statement.executeQuery()` method to invoke your query and assign it to your `ResultSet`, e.g.

   ```
   ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(EntryValues) FROM Entries");
   ```
3. Your result is one simple '*row*' therefore you can use

   ```
   if(rs.next()) {  // check if a result was returned
     String avg = rs.getString(1); // get your result
   }
   ```

If your result contains multiple rows you'll have to use a *while-loop* for example to iterate through all the result entries:

```
while(rs.next()) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Hope this helpes, have Fun!